# VS Reporting Services - [rsInvalidFormatString] The Format value for the textrun is not valid

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I wrote code in SQL Server that gives the year, the month and some data for those months in separate columns. The column for month (MM) gives months in numeric digits (1 to 12).

The code I used was:

```
Select   ....
        ,Month(IRDate) AS MM
        ,...
```

I created a report in MS VS Report builder and included all the data in table columns. The report runs fine. However, at the bottom I get the below warning message:

> [rsInvalidFormatString] The Format value for the textrun
>   ‘MM.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ is not valid. Format specifier was
>   invalid.

I checked the formatting for that cell, it is set to default - No formatting.

In the report, I've set the parameter to have a default value as

```
=DateValue("September 01, 2016")
```

Would that be the issue? Maybe the default value is not the right format? I removed the default value and kept it as no specified value. Warning message still comes up.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the error message '[rsInvalidFormatString] The Format value for the textrun....'  is a log message. Rectifying the problem does not take away the message because it is a log message. So even after you correct the issue, the message will still show.

The only way to remove that message is to simply restart Visual Studio. When Visual Studio starts back up, the log is cleared and you won't see the message any more.

"Who knew healthcare would be so complicated?" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried formatting the textbox properties that holds the MM value to be a number datatype with no decimal places?

Regarding your other question about the default parameter value, I have typically seen DateValue formatted as such: 9/1/2016

Also, is your parameter datatype set to Date/Time?

Comment: Glad you figured it out!